# Door log report datediff SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, datediff

I'm currently trying to produce data for when employees swipe in and out of various doors in the building. The data is saved in a table like -

[image]

Ideally id like to do a `datediff` for the minutes but am struggling to get it to work! anyone have any thoughts as to the best way forward?

Answer (score 2):

you can try this way,

```
select uid, serialno, datediff(m, max(time), min(time) ) from tablename 
group by uid, serialno
```

Comment: issue i'm having is that for example the upstairs npc can be in and out 6 times in a day meaning a max and min will on get me the initial and final time difference - sorry should have been clearer

Answer (score 0):

Group on `userId, serialNumber, max(time) and min(time)` and then add a calculated column with the time difference.